# How can I change the value of a command in the enumerate environment?

Tags: macros, enumerate, variable

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\myvalue}{0}
    \newcommand{\setmyvalue}[1]{\renewcommand{\myvalue}{#1}}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First Point. \setmyvalue{1}
    \end{enumerate}
Value: \myvalue
\end{document}
```

Returns a value of 0, instead of the intended value 1. Why's that and how can I correct the code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Any LaTeX environment creates a group, and a `\newcommand` is local to the current group, so once LaTeX finds the `\end{enumerate}` your definition is lost. You can change the definition of `\setmyvalue` to `\newcommand{\setmyvalue}[1]{\global\def\myvalue{#1}}`, so `\myvalue` will be a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general command definitions are local to the environment they're made in. In your case, a redefinition (`\renewcommand`) doesn't affect the global view for `\myvalue`. For that you'd need to use something like

```
\newcommand{\setmyvalue}{\gdef\myvalue}
```

which will make the (re)`def`inition of `\myvalue` `g`lobal.

It might be more feasible to change `\myvalue` to resemble a counter:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{myvalue}% Default of myvalue is 0
\newcommand{\setmyvalue}{\setcounter{myvalue}}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First Point. \setmyvalue{1}
\end{enumerate}
Value: \themyvalue

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, typing error. Unfortunately this didn't change the resulting 0 though

Comment: @WuaghhhhXMA: M'kay. I've updated the answer to use an alternative - counters, rather than plain macros, which aren't bound by localized environment changes. Or, you could use `\gdef` instead.

Comment: Thanks, then it seems that my problem is actually a bigger one, because I wanted to expand a list, which was implemented as a command (and not a def). This didn't work as intended, when I changed the definition to work with def, as I unfortunately have not yet a deeper understanding in the differences between those.

Comment: @WuaghhhhXMA: well, perhaps you should rephrase your question to include your use-case. Then one can provide a more adequate suggestion/solution.

Comment: Oh, didn't know, that this would be the adequate reaction, as I thought, the main solution has been answered. Just bewfore you answered , I opened a new question regarding the more complex problem though

Comment: @WuaghhhhXMA: You could "close" this question by marking it as "solved" (the green check mark under the voting buttons).